# notifyDataSetChanged() recyclerview, only first cell clicked changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in fragment, with the contents of the cells changing as the user clicks on it.

After the users clicks the item, the contents is changed. However, this only works the first time, but when I click a different row they are not changing. Now, the data source data is changing, because if i exit the activity and go back in, the correct data is shown. Why would this be.

What I really don't understand is, that when I debug, I go through the adatper each time, and the data is correct, and it shows me that it is executing the code that changed the cell appearance, but it doesn't actually change!

Here is my fragment:

```
public class AerobicFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "999.AerobicFragment";
public static final String JSON_STRING_EXERCISES = "999.JSON_STRING_EXERCISES";
private RecyclerView exerciseRecyclerView;
private ExerciseAdapter exerciseAdapter;
public ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseList;

public static final int REQUEST_CODE_ADD_EXERCISE = 394;
private boolean aerobicExerciseSetUp;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aerobic, container, false);

    exerciseList = new ArrayList<>();

    exerciseList = SharedPreferencesManager.getAerobicExercisesList(getContext());

    Log.d(TAG, "Aerobic Exercise List Size: " + exerciseList.size());

    aerobicExerciseSetUp = SharedPreferencesManager.getAerobicExercisesCreated(getContext());

    if(!aerobicExerciseSetUp){
        showDialog();
    }



    exerciseRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.exercise_recycler_view);
    exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseAdapter(exerciseList);


    exerciseRecyclerView.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);
    exerciseRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


    exerciseAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExerciseAdapter.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final int position, View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick pos = " + position);

            int timesLeftInt = Integer.parseInt(exerciseList.get(position).getTimesPerWeek()) - exerciseList.get(position).getTimesDoneThisWeek();



            if(timesLeftInt != 0){

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage("Did you do your " + exerciseList.get(position).getNameOfExercise() +
                        " for " + exerciseList.get(position).getDurationOfExercise() + "?")
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                int newTimesDoneThisWeek = exerciseList.get(position).getTimesDoneThisWeek();
                                newTimesDoneThisWeek++;

                                exerciseList.get(position).setTimesDoneThisWeek(newTimesDoneThisWeek);



                                SharedPreferencesManager.setAerobicExercisesList(getContext(), exerciseList);


                                exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
                // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                builder.create();
                builder.show();



            }


        }
    });




    return v;
}

private void showDialog() {

    if(!aerobicExerciseSetUp){


        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No aerobic exercises are set up yet");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you wish to add an aerobic exercise now?");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes please",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), TypeOfAerobicExerciseActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ADD_EXERCISE);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Not now",
                new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        alertDialog.show();
    }


}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {


    }
    else {
    }
}



public static AerobicFragment newInstance(String text) {

    AerobicFragment f = new AerobicFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
```

And here is the Adapter:

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


private static final String TAG = "999.ExerciseAdapter";
private static ClickListener clickListener;



public ImageView exerciseItemIcon;
public TextView exerciseNameTextView;
public TextView exerciseDurationTextView;
public TextView exerciseTimesRemainingTextView;
public TextView exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView;

ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public ExerciseAdapter(ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseArrayList) {

    this.exerciseArrayList = exerciseArrayList;

}


public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}


class ExerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ExerciseViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        exerciseNameTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_name_textView);
        exerciseDurationTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_duration_textview);
        exerciseTimesRemainingTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_times_remaining_textview);
        exerciseItemIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_item_icon);
        exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timesRemainingConstantTextView);
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }


}

public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    ExerciseAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
}

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on positio

n
            // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
//            return position % 2 * 2;
            return position;
        }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return exerciseArrayList.size();
}

@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {



        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.exercise_item_row, parent, false);



        return new ExerciseViewHolder(itemView);

    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        ExerciseViewHolder exerciseViewHolder = (ExerciseViewHolder) holder;
        exerciseNameTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getNameOfExercise());
        exerciseDurationTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getDurationOfExercise());


        int timesRemainingThisWeek = Integer.parseInt(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getTimesPerWeek())
                                            - exerciseArrayList.get(position).getTimesDoneThisWeek();

        Log.d(TAG, "Times remaining: " + timesRemainingThisWeek);

        if (timesRemainingThisWeek != 0){
            exerciseTimesRemainingTextView.setText("" + timesRemainingThisWeek);
            exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            exerciseTimesRemainingTextView.setText("DONE");
            exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }



        exerciseItemIcon.setImageResource(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getExerciseIcon());






        }
    }
```

Here is my xml for the item row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" 

encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_exercise"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/exercise_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/exercise_swimming_icon"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Swimming"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/exercise_name_textView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="2dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20 minutes"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/exercise_duration_textview"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="2dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/exercise_times_remaining_textview"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:padding="2dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="time(s) remaining"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/timesRemainingConstantTextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:padding="2dp"/>




</LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks so much

Comment: see the edit in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific adapter position in the list use

[`notifyItemChanged (int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))

method.

Edit: Can you replace your `onBindViewHolder` method with the code below and try with it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ExerciseViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.exerciseNameTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getNameOfExercise());
    holder.exerciseDurationTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getDurationOfExercise());


    int timesRemainingThisWeek = Integer.parseInt(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getTimesPerWeek())
                                        - exerciseArrayList.get(position).getTimesDoneThisWeek();

    Log.d(TAG, "Times remaining: " + timesRemainingThisWeek);

    if (timesRemainingThisWeek != 0){
        holder.exerciseTimesRemainingTextView.setText("" + timesRemainingThisWeek);
        holder.exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        holder.exerciseTimesRemainingTextView.setText("DONE");
        holder.exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }



    holder.exerciseItemIcon.setImageResource(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getExerciseIcon());

}
```

Edit 2: You need to fix superclass definition also. Use the code below for the adapter.

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ExerciseViewHolder> {


private static final String TAG = "999.ExerciseAdapter";
private static ClickListener clickListener;



public ImageView exerciseItemIcon;
public TextView exerciseNameTextView;
public TextView exerciseDurationTextView;
public TextView exerciseTimesRemainingTextView;
public TextView exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView;

ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public ExerciseAdapter(ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseArrayList) {

    this.exerciseArrayList = exerciseArrayList;

}


public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}


class ExerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ExerciseViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        exerciseNameTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_name_textView);
        exerciseDurationTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_duration_textview);
        exerciseTimesRemainingTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_times_remaining_textview);
        exerciseItemIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_item_icon);
        exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timesRemainingConstantTextView);
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }


}

public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    ExerciseAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
}

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
            // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
//            return position % 2 * 2;
            return position;
        }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return exerciseArrayList.size();
}

@Override
    public ExerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {



        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.exercise_item_row, parent, false);



        return new ExerciseViewHolder(itemView);

    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ExerciseViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.exerciseNameTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getNameOfExercise());
    holder.exerciseDurationTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getDurationOfExercise());


    int timesRemainingThisWeek = Integer.parseInt(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getTimesPerWeek())
                                        - exerciseArrayList.get(position).getTimesDoneThisWeek();

    Log.d(TAG, "Times remaining: " + timesRemainingThisWeek);

    if (timesRemainingThisWeek != 0){
        holder.exerciseTimesRemainingTextView.setText("" + timesRemainingThisWeek);
        holder.exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        holder.exerciseTimesRemainingTextView.setText("DONE");
        holder.exerciseTimesRemainingCONSTANTTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }



    holder.exerciseItemIcon.setImageResource(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getExerciseIcon());

}
```

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: can you share your xml?

Answer (score 0):

try this code on your click event

put below code after this line

```
 exerciseList.get(position).setTimesDoneThisWeek(newTimesDoneThisWeek);

ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseListTemp =exerciseList;
exerciseList.clear();
exerciseList.addAll(exerciseListTemp );
exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: After I did this, the list was empty. I don't know why the line: exerciseList.addAll(exerciseListTemp ); didn't work.